# Изменение шаблонной переменной на ходу

Tags: angular2

Я заметил, что значение шаблонной переменной меняется только после того, как будет нажата клавиша Enter или покинуто поле.

Так вот, можно ли сделать так, что бы оно менялось в момент ввода?

Например,

```
<input id="search" type="search" class="form-control" name="search" placeholder="Search" #searchValue/>
<div *ngIf="searchValue.value" class="serach-result col-xs-2">
  <div *ngFor="let tag of tags">{{tag}}</div>
</div>
```

перечисление элементов отображается после покидания поля, а нужно в момент ввода отображать результаты.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/user-input

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь `ngModel`

```
<input type="search" class="form-control"  placeholder="Search" [(ngModel)]="searchValue">
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngmodel